# Select from dropdown always return first record?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with dropdown, i always get first record. Any suggestion?

```
$category = $request->input('article_category');

<select class="form-control" name="article_category">
    <option value="" disabled>--Please select article category</option>
          @foreach ($categories as $category)
           <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>
           @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the following change...

```
<select class="form-control" name="article_category">
  <option value="" disabled>--Please select article category</option>
  @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}" @if(request()->input('article_category') == $category->id){{ 'selected' }}@endif>{{ $category->title }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

1. Your `$category = $request->input('article_category')` was getting **overwritten** by the `foreach($categories as $category)` written in foreach.
2. Also, you must add the **selected** keyword to mark the option as selected on page load.

Comment: same problem..in database it saves first from dropdown what ever i choose

Comment: @uzhas What are you passing into your view?

Comment: @uzhas Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: I'd recommend to use `{{ request->article_category == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}` instead of `@if` clause here. In my opinion it's more readable.